# Cannot load Img/svg in my angular project

Tags: html, angular, image, svg

So I just started a new project
and I already have a folder with images inside
I moved the folder into my project and now the folder it's under the folder src
***( project/src/images )***
now in my app.component.html i am using:

```
<img src = "../images/shared/logo.svg"
```

the logo.svg is located in shared folder that is in images folder ***(project/src/images/shared/logo.svg)***

I used "../" at the start to go one folder back from app folder where app.component.html is located in..

anywayy when I am loading the page with npm start
it wont load the photo/img/icon..
also in the console it says :
***logo.svg:1 GET http://localhost:4200/images/shared/logo.svg 404 (Not Found)***

Comment: check base href value in html it should be ` \ `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default [Anular project structure](https://angular.io/guide/file-structure) has a dedicated folder *src/assets* where you should keep your image and other asset files. It's possible to configure assets folder in *angular.json*

```
"assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"]
```

However the easist way to solve your problem is to move *images* folder to *src/assets*

```
<img src="assets/images/shared/logo.svg" />
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Alway we need think that Angular create in a "folder"  (in develop is in memory) one .index.html, some .js files and one .css. Futhermore copy your files in "assets" folder (or whatever you indicate in the assets array in angular.json) in a folder called "assets". So, from index.html, the images are in "assets", the .css with url should refer to "assets", the .json you read are in "assets", etc.

Answer (score 0):

In my scenerio, I have added the relative path like

```
 <img src="../../../../../../apps/ngshop/src/assets/images/banner-image.svg" alt="" />
```

This is wrong in angular. Then I changed to like below and it worked fine

```
  <img src="assets/images/banner-image.svg" alt="" />
```

Because, We are already declaring **assets** folder in **project.json** or **angular.json**

```
        "polyfills": ["zone.js"],
        "tsConfig": "apps/ngshop/tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": ["apps/ngshop/src/favicon.ico", "apps/ngshop/src/assets"],
        "styles": ["apps/ngshop/src/styles.scss"],
        "scripts": []
```